# Name for a classification card with yes/no questions

Tags: single-word-requests

How would I call this kind of map / decision tree, typically used by scouts, to identify different kinds of trees, plants, mushrooms, birds, butterflies, etc.?

On every node, there is a yes/no question, and depending on the answer you go to one of the children nodes. You repeat this until you are in a leaf node which gives you the name of the thing you are identifying.

I have tried searching for images with {mushroom, tree, bird} {classification, identification} {tree, map, [search] card} [scouts] but haven't been able to find anything in English, so I think there is some idiomatic expressing that I'm missing. The below image is in Dutch, [found](https://activiteitenbank.scouting.nl/index.php/component/k2/item/463-Op_zoek_in_de_natuur) by the term "zoekkaart" (search card/map).

Example sentence: "Follow the directions on the X to {identify, classify} the observed item."

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a [*dichotomous key*](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomous_key).

Comment: Thanks very much. Is that also the word kids would use for it, or do you know of a simpler alternative?

Comment: @Keelan Maybe something like _identification key_ or _identification tree_?

Comment: This is the correct answer for this kind of decision tree. I think even elementary-age kids would know the term if they have had a teacher who had done a lesson on it. https://www.teachingchannel.org/videos/dichotomous-key

Comment: I've usually heard this referred to simply as a *key* by botanists.

Comment: @tchrist Sure, the _dichotomous_ simply means divided into two branches (i.e. at each yes/no node)

Answer (score 1):

A more general term for such a thing could be a ***[flowchart](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flowchart)***:

> a diagram that shows step-by-step progression through a procedure or system especially using connecting lines and a set of conventional symbols
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flowchart)*</sub>

Using that term instead of your *{tree, map, [search] card}* element got me what I think is a very promising set of [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%7Bmushroom,%20tree,%20bird%7D%20%7Bclassification,%20identification%7D%20%7Bflowchart%7D%20%5Bscouts%5D&client=firefox-b-1&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6rKSaufbXAhVL4IMKHVTJCOMQ7AkIOg&biw=1582&bih=768)...